# SFDX CLI: Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: inactive user

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

After running the command:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --setdefaultdevhubusername
```

And getting a successful result:

> Successfully authorized robs@example.com with org ID 00D4J000000EmuiXXX

I then run the command:

```
sfdx force:org:shape:list
```

And get this error:

> Error (1): Error authenticating with the refresh token due to: inactive user

I am the system admin on the org.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to log out your user with the following command
sfdx force:auth:logout -u robs@example.com.dev
Close the project/VSCode and reopen again
And then you have to authorise again against the org.

Comment: Why in Gods name should any of this be necessary...